# Auto Increment in FoxPro 2.0

Tags: increment, foxpro, legacy

I'm doing some legacy work and I've been asked to add an auto increment ID column to an existing FoxPro 2.0 table. All of my searches are returning Visual FoxPro docs and converting this project to VFP is not an option. So my question is simply this: does FoxPro 2.0 support auto increment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foxpro version 2.0 does not have an auto increment field type. Auto increment was added in Visual Foxpro.

To add auto increment in Foxpro 2.0, you must write a routine to do this.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thank you very much!

Comment: The AutoInc field type wasn't even in Visual FoxPro versions 3, 5, 6 or 7 - it first appeared in version 8.